# What is the static_path parameter in Flask.__init__?

Tags: python, flask

The signature of `Flask.__init__` has a `static_path` parameter, but it's not documented. What does that parameter do?

```
class Flask(
    import_name,
    static_path=None, static_url_path=None, static_folder='static',
    template_folder='templates',
    instance_path=None, instance_relative_config=False, root_path=None
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the old name for `static_url_path`. It is deprecated and will be removed in the 1.0 release. It was changed because `static_path` and `static_folder` were too easy to confuse.